# material control issue on large objects (solved)

Tags: rendering

I recently prepared a car model and made its platform. I made the color between black and gray when I was making the platform, but unfortunately I cannot change that right now. actually I am changing it, but this is not quite right.

[image]

[image]

how can i solve this problem? thanks.

Comment: You're looking at two different materials in these screenshots.  Is that what you meant?
Tiles.002 and Tiles.001

Comment: sorry :) unfortunately i didn't realize but what you said is true. i realized it 2 minutes after i made this post. In fact, there are 5-10 platforms. that is why it is intertwined. and shade was in smooth mode. Turning it off fixed it. thank you...